# Issue trying to ordering using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sorting

I have a directory with files named by "Artist [Style] Number.ext"

An example:

```
Atomix [Dubstep] 01.avi
Atomix [Rock] 02.wmv
Atomix [Rock] 03.avi

Lacuna [Rock] 01.mp4
Lacuna [Rock] 02.avi
```

I want to use **LINQ** to list the files to group them by Artists, in the ordering I want to include only one "[style]" and then sort each artist by file extension, for example like this where I have included only the "[Rock]" style:

```
Atomix [Rock] 03.avi
Atomix [Rock] 02.wmv
Lacuna [Rock] 02.avi
Lacuna [Rock] 01.mp4
```

"A" goes first than "L" and "avi" goes first than "wmv", That's my desired result but what I get when trying to ordering is this kind of sort:

```
Atomix [Rock] 03.avi
Lacuna [Rock] 02.avi
Lacuna [Rock] 01.mp4
Atomix [Rock] 02.wmv
```

The artists are mixed but the extensions are sorted, "avi" goes first than "mp4" when sorting but "A" of "Atomix" goes first than "L" of "Lacuna", I don't know how to correct this.

This is the instruction I'm using with the filenames I've said before:

```
    Dim Videos As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
    Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Extension) _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("[rock]")) _
    .ToList
```

PS: I've tried to toggle the order of the methods but I get the same result.

> UPDATE:

I've tried to use the @jyparask solution but I still need some modification to get the extensions ordered, this is what I get:

```
Aa [Style] 04.mp4
Ab [Style] 01.wmv
Ab [Style] 03.wmv
Ab [Style] 05.mp4
Ab [Style] 05.wmv
Ab [Style] 06.mp4
Ab [Style] 07.mp4
Ab [Style] 09999999999964.mp4
Ac [Style] 166333226.mp4
Ac [Style] 333133333333313313322.mp4
Ac [Style] 44.mp4
Ac [Style] 6049.wmv
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
    Dim Videos As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
    Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("[word]")) _
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name) _
    .ThenBy(Function(x) x.Extension) _
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first OrderBy the Artist and use ThenBy passing the extension.

```
Dim Videos As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name.Substring(0,x.Name.IndexOf("["))) _
.ThenBy(Function(x) x.Extension) _
.Where(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("[rock]")) _
.ToList
```

Comment: the x.Artists it's a joke right? Well I tell you I didnt set the artist name anywhere because for taking the artists name I can use directly the "Name" property of the fileinfo object then I don't need to compare between Artists anmes, so I've changed your "x.Artists" to "x.Name" and now the Filenames are ordered but the extensions are mixed.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding. Please see my Update.